# In ASP.NET, how can you "reset" and go back to the original state, pre postbacks?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, postback

I am very new to ASP.NET. I just learned what postbacks are and I am trying to handle them, however, I would like to know if there is a way to "reset" the page. As in go to the original state of the page, before any postbacks were handled.

This will clear out any text boxes, check boxes, etc. In effect clearing any and all cache. Make it look like the user just opened the page fresh for the first time. Would like it to be a button called "reset" or "Start over".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you're done with your data, I would simply suggest doing a `Response.Redirect("~/Example.aspx")` to the same page. That way you're not passing the ViewState back to the page.

**Example.aspx**

```
<asp:Button id="Reset" Text="Reset" runat="server" OnClick="Reset_Click" />
```

**Example.aspx.cs**

```
protected void Reset_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { 
    Session["ViewState"] = null; 
    Response.Redirect("~/Example.aspx"); 
}
```

Comment: This isnt working for me.  I only have 1 aspx page, that has hidden place holders, and as you check boxes, I dynamically create a table with text boxes and other controls and dump them into the place holders, then visible=true the place holders.  When I just do a redirect, these place holders are still filled and visible.

Comment: Yes, same page.

    protected void buttonRestart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
            Session["ViewState"] = null;
            Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx");
        }

Comment: and is that method firing when you click the button? add `Response.Write("I Fired");` just before your redirect in order to make sure that your method is in fact firing.

Comment: I dont know what Response.Write did (i didnt get a dialog or anything) but I put a break point in the method and it did break.

Comment: Response.Write will write out `I Fired` at the very top of your page.

Comment: Stale dll maybe, happens sometimes.

Comment: have you got `OnClick="Reset_Click"` added to your reset button in your aspx page?

Comment: Yes, as it does break.  I think I have found my issue.  There were static members in the class.  I should remove them, but for now I will do a if(!Page.isPostBack){ static_members = null; }.  I believe this should do it.   The redirect is what I needed!

Answer (score 2):

In the OnClick handler of the button, you could do a `Response.Redirect` to the same page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the HTML input element with a type="reset":

`<input type="reset" value="Reset" />`

Comment: That won't work if the fields have changed during a postback; because the 'original' values of the form fields according to the HTML form itself are the 'new' values that were submitted at the last postback.

Answer (score -1):

```
    <asp:Button ID="Reset" runat="server" Text="Reset" align="center" 
        onclick="Reset_Click"  />

    protected void Reset_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Session["ViewState"] = null;
        Response.Redirect("~/Form.aspx");
    }
```

Comment: This just repeats what the answers from two years prior suggest.